# iOS VoiceOver: any good way to focus on navigation title when screen appears?

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

By default the VoiceOver focuses on the Back button, I need it to focus on the title of the navigation bar. I did a few searches and researches, so far I've found workarounds:

1. Set the back button to `nil` when screen appears and re-set it to a non-nil value after some delay, to force VO focus on the next element which is the title.
2. Hard code an index to get the actual view for the navigation title as the navigation bar's subview.

They should work but none of them is ideal, I've tried:

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    UIAccessibility.post(notification: .screenChanged, argument: navigationController?.navigationBar)
}
```

Just to see what happens, it ends up still focusing on the back button which is expected because the back button is also an element in `navigationBar` and probably earlier than the title.

I know I can have custom view for the navigation title but consider I have to do this for all the screens, before going that route, I wonder if there's a good way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only this way we can achieve this voice-over by posting a notification.

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .screenChanged, argument: navigationController?.navigationBar)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it, not working :-(